# Catch all exception in Vue action

Tags: javascript, exception, promise, vue.js, vuex

While developing sometime I mistype the name of a new variable. An exception is thrown, but if the code is called in the context of a Promise in a Vue action, this exception is not logged on the console.

Say a Vue action returns a Promise that throws an exception:

```
export const debug = ({}) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        throw 'MyError';
    });
}
```

When a `dispatch` calls that action, the exception is silenced and never logged on the console. What is the best way to make sure to report the problem ?

One obvious way is to add a `catch` for each `dispatch` (or for each action) that will take care of logging the error:

```
// Each action
export const debug = ({}) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        throw 'MyError';
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
    });
}

// Each dispatch
this.$store.dispatch('debug')
.catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
});
```

That solution looks heavy for just logging errors. After all, the point here is not to gracefully recover from an error, but to log what would be reported if called outside of a Vuex action context.

Vuex wraps the actions promises with a `catch` that emits the `vuex:error` message (see vuex `store.js`):

```
function registerAction (store, type, handler, local) {
  const entry = store._actions[type] || (store._actions[type] = [])
  entry.push(function wrappedActionHandler (payload, cb) {
    let res = handler({
      dispatch: local.dispatch,
      commit: local.commit,
      getters: local.getters,
      state: local.state,
      rootGetters: store.getters,
      rootState: store.state
    }, payload, cb)
    if (!isPromise(res)) {
      res = Promise.resolve(res)
    }
    if (store._devtoolHook) {
      return res.catch(err => {
        store._devtoolHook.emit('vuex:error', err)
        throw err
      })
    } else {
      return res
    }
  })
}
```

A generic handler could react to `vuex:error`, but as `store._devtoolHook` doesn't exist in production, that solution doesn't seem right as well.

What is the best way to handle Promises that throws exception in the context of a Vuex action ?

Comment: You should get an `unhandled rejection` in the console from that code. What promise library or browser are you using?

Comment: Chromium Version 56.0.2924.76 Built on Ubuntu , running on Ubuntu 16.10 (64-bit)
In package.json: promise ^7.1.1

Comment: Try native promises. Or see here how to un-silence them: https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise#unhandled-rejections

Comment: Thanks @Bergi, that was very useful.